# Forward all Subdomains to another domain (with subdomain intact)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I have moved a lot of people off one of my servers. Each person had an account using subdomains so `urn.example.com` `urn2.example.com`. What I would like to do is set it up so ANY subdomain accessed on the `example.com` domain is automatically forwarded to the correct subdomain on `example.co.uk` domain.

So `urn.example.com` would go to `urn.example.co.uk`.

I'm not that up on DNS so I don't really know what I am looking for.

I have set up an A Record for `*.example.com` pointing to the IP address of `example.co.uk` 
thinking that "may" work but it hasn't.

EDIT: I have now set up a `*.example.com` CNAME record pointing to `example.co.uk.` I am waiting to see if it works.

Comment: A records are direct pointers from hostname to IP address, try it with a CNAME record, which is an alias pointer where you can do something like you are already trying.

Comment: @Tim - Made the change, will wait for propagation and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify I have done this correctly, I have added a record against `example.com` where subdomain is `*`, type is `CNAME` and domain is `example.co.uk.` That correct?

Comment: Are you running other services beside HTTP? If not, then what web server are you using?

Comment: @Mircea - Sorry I am not sure I follow what you mean. I am running Linux Centos with CPanel / WHM. It is only used as a web server if that is what you mean.

Comment: All those virtual hosts have the same IP address? If you do not have SSL enabled hosts, then you can host all of them on one single IP.

Comment: @Mircea - They are on different servers as they are VPS's.

Comment: Am I just over complicating this ... If I set the domain to forward to another one. Wouldn't the subdomains forward as well?

Comment: No, it will not "forward". Each subdomain can have its own IP that is different from the parent domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

*.domain.com > *.domain.co.uk

And have the * host specification match up correctly.

If yes, then I suggest creating *.domain.com and then using Rewrite Rules to do a permanment redirect to the co.uk domain.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301]
```

This is just a stab at the rewrite rule  - it has not been tested.  The idea is to catch the sub domain name in back reference and then pass it into your new URL.

Comment: Ok, thats a sound idea. Can you just clarify what you mean about "create a *.domain.com". Do you mean host domain.com somewhere and just rewrite everthing then forward?

Comment: *.domain.com is just a wild card domain name. This is required so the same domain will answer for all sub domains.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that what you want to do can be done using DNS alone.  I'd setup a virtual host for *.example.com which does a 301 (permanant) redirect to the correct example.co.uk url.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation / tutorials on doing this? All this stuff is rather new to me.